# DoubleClick Floodlight not recording correct data

Tags: google-tag-manager, double-click, google-floodlight

My DoubleClick Floodlight is not recording my data correctly, it sometimes get the actually custom variable name (enclosed in []), and sometimes the actual data

This is a sample data that i'm getting

```
 | Field_1     | Field_2
1| [field_1]   | [field_2]
2| sample text | another sample text
```

Sample code

```
var axel = Math.random() + "";
var a = axel * 10000000000000;
document.write('<iframe class="fl-tags" src="https://1234567.fls.doubleclick.net/activityi;src=1234567;type=type;cat=cat;u1='+ cart['data_1'] + ';u2='+ cart['data_2'] + ';ord=1;num=' + a + '?" width="1" height="1" frameborder="0" style="display:none"></iframe>');
```

DoubleClick Floodlight setup

```
u1 = data type string, name field_1
u2 = data type string, name field_2
```

Why is DC FL getting the actually variable name and not getting the actual data? has anyone encountered this before?

Answer (score 0):

In case you haven't solved yet, the issue is how you are invoking the dynamic variables in the floodlight tag.

You need to create a global variable in your code or create a GTM variable to reference. The variable should be placed within curly brackets {{variable}} in the floodlight pixel. FLS uses the {{ }} to signal a global variable needs to be referenced.
ex:

```
var axel = Math.random() + "";
var a = axel * 10000000000000;
document.write('<iframe class="fl-tags" src="https://1234567.fls.doubleclick.net/activityi;src=1234567;type=type;cat=cat;u1={{data_1}};u2={{data_2}};ord=1;num=' + a + '?" width="1" height="1" frameborder="0" style="display:none"></iframe>');
```